# Error when i run sudo rake dtach:install in Rhosync

Tags: android, ruby, rhomobile

I'm following the rhosync installation guide.

$rhosync app storemanager-server

$cd storemanager-server
$sudo rake dtach:install

I get the following error:

(in /projects/sharath apps/sharatapp/storemanager-server)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rhosync/tasks
/projects/sharath apps/sharatapp/storemanager-server/Rakefile:5:in `require'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

i dont know where i am going wrong

i tried writing

export RUBYOPT=rubygems
in .profile

but still it not working

when i run **gem env** commend 
this is the following output

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/sharath/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: did you install the rhosync gem? `gem install rhosync`? You can find out by running `gem which rhosync`. If installed it will printout the location of the gem.

Comment: ya i got the following output **/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rhosync-2.1.16/lib/rhosync.rb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  install dtach as

sudo apt-get install dtach (Ubuntu)

and sloved the problem